# How to switch certificates in AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I am very new to this and struggling to understand AWS.

I had a single domain `foo.mydomain.com`.  This was registered in Route53.  And there was a certificate in AWS Certificate Manager that mapped to it.

Now I have two domains `foo.mydomain.com` & `bar.mydomain.com`.  I have registered the latter in Route53.  And I have requrested and received a new certificate from AWS Certificate Manager.  This one maps to *both* domains (via the "additional names" property).

How can I simply disable the old certificate and enable the new certificate?

[image: screen shot of AWS Certificate Manager]

I want the values for `In use?` above to be swapped.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the services where you are utilizing these certificates (Load Balancers, CloudFront distributions or API Gateways) and change the certificate they are using there.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Certificate Manager manages the SSL/TLS certificates. In general certificates are configured and consumed on the services like ALB (application load balancer), API Gateway, Virtual Machine, Cloudfront etc. If you would like to update the certificate, modify the configuration on one of the above services as applicable in your case. While changing configuration you have to choose the right certificate from ACM. Once update is successful you will see the status in ACM.

Here is an AWS documentation explains how to install/Update SSL Certificates:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-certificates.html